# asp:calendar automatically select Sunday

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, web

I have got a small form going on and would like to set my Calendar to automatically select upcoming Sunday, how could i achieve that? I have a feeling i have to do something onload but not sure what.

Thank You

Comment: All upcoming sunday in month or only next sunday you want to select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go...

Using this method, you can set the date for whatever next day of the week you decide, not just Sunday, which makes it flexible:

```
public static DateTime GetNextWeekday(DayOfWeek day)
{
    DateTime start = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);

    int days = ((int)day - (int)start.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7;

    return start.AddDays(days);
}
```

Then on your PageLoad:

```
DateTime nextSunday = GetNextWeekday(DayOfWeek.Sunday);
yourCalendarControl.SelectedDate = nextSunday;
```

Comment: The name 'GetNextWeekday' does not exist in the current context?? Not sure about this.

Comment: Fixed the typo on the method.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            DateTime nextSunday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(7 -(int) DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek); 
            Calendar1.SelectedDate = nextSunday;
}
```